# How Can I get ChillBox (a LightBox clone) to work on an offline webapp using cache.manifest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, lightbox2, cache-manifest

I am building a web app for an iPad (designed so my boss can show information at meetings).
So far I have everything working, except for one thing- I am using an application cache to allow the app to work offline (cache.manifest), and for some reason, when I go offline, I can not get any sort of lightbox type script to work.
When I am connected to the internet everything functions as desired, but as soon as I disconnect the images open on a new page in Safari instead of showing in a lightbox.
Currently I am using ChillBox ( http://www.chillwebdesigns.co.uk/chillbox ), but I have also used SlimBox and it had the same problem. (I tried LightBox 2, but it failed for other reasons.)

I have all the images in my manifest, as well as all the .js files.
The links are all formatted as such:

```
<a href="path/to/image.gif" rel="ChillBox" title="A title" class="lb">
    <img src="path/to/image.gif" alt="" />
</a>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears to be solved. I was loading the chillbox.js inline after the set of links that it applied to. This worked online, but failed offline. Putting the link to the js in the head of the parent file seems to have fixed this for now!